# How do I keep a connection open to my mobile application?

Tags: android

I want to keep a connection alive to my Android application so that when the server wishes to communicate to the device (ie. send new data) to be able to do so. I do not want to use external API's or requests from the mobile; just a connection that stays idle until I send data from my server. What would be the simple way to go with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to keep the connection alive when your app is running, do the following:

> If your application makes constant use of the network, it's probably
>   most efficient to set up a single instance of RequestQueue that will
>   last the lifetime of your app.

From here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html

Otherwise, Google Cloud Messaging is the right approach: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into Google Cloud Messaging for Android, see [the overview page here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)